# How to aggregate an array of object properties based on two criteria inside each object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Lets say i have this array of objects:

```
[{
  a: "test", b: "5", c: 4
},
{
  a: "test 2", b: "2", c: 10
},
{
  a: "test", b: "5", c: 66
}]
```

I want aggregate the objects where properties `a` & `b` are equal in each object, so i end up with:

```
[{
   a: "test", b: "5", c: 70
},
{
   a: "test 2", b: "2", c: 10
}]
```

I can manage this in a couple of for loops e.g.

```
const a = [];
for(let item of data) {
    const dateTime  = new Date(item.T);
    const time = dateTime.getHours()+":"+dateTime.getMinutes()+":"+dateTime.getSeconds();
    const id = item.p+time+item.m;

    if (a[id]) {
        a[id].q = (parseFloat(a[id].q) + parseFloat(item.q)).toFixed(8)
    } else {
        a[id] = item;
    }
}
const b = [];
for (var key in a) { 
    b.push(a[key]); // converts to numbered array
}
return b;
```

...but i was wondering if there was a more optimal way?

Comment: what does not work with your code?

Comment: It works, i'm look at optimizing

Comment: @HGPB please check my updated answer.

Comment: Your code does not seem to work on your example data, it operates on  `.T` and `.q` properties not `a` and `b`?

Comment: Since your `id`s are strings, don't use an `[]` array for your `a`. Use either `{}` or even better a `Map`.

Comment: What does that date and number manipulation have to do with the question?

Comment: @Bergi you are quite right.

Comment: @trincot My question is a simplified version of my code that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

I think this is optimized since you are looping only once. I also tried to optimize as much as I could.

```js
const data = [
  { a: "test", b: "5", c: 4 },
  { a: "test 2", b: "2", c: 10 },
  { a: "test", b: "5", c: 66 }
]

function agregate(arr) {
  const result = [];
  const cache = {};
  const len = arr.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    const item = arr[i];
    const itemC = item.c;
    const key = JSON.stringify({ a: item.a, b: item.b });

    // If is already cached, just agregates the c property.
    if (cache[key]) {
      cache[key][0] += itemC;
      result[cache[key][1]].c += itemC;
    } else {
      // Pushes into result and updates the cache {key} = [c value, index].
      result.push(item);
      cache[key] = [itemC, result.length - 1];
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.time('Agregate');
console.log(agregate(data));
console.timeEnd('Agregate');
```

Comment: I thought the code should sum the "c" field? I think your one doesn't. :)

Comment: @drinchev is ok now :)

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be marginally faster than my example coming in at 1.2 to 2.9 ms to run the function over a 1000 records.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more abstract way of doing this with `reduce`, but I'm just scratching my brain here.

```js
const input = [
    {
        a : "test", b : "5", c : 4
    },
    {
        a : "test 2", b : "2", c : 10
    },
    {
        a : "test", b : "5", c : 66
    }
];

/**
 * Will sum all fields except the one specified in fields, which will group
 *
 * @param input    The input array
 * @param fields   The fields that needs to be grouped
 * @returns {*}
 */
function sumGroup( input, fields ) {
    return input.reduce( ( result, item ) => {

        /** Get all keys of the current item ... ["a","b","c"...] */
        const itemKeys = Object.keys( item );

        /** Get the grouped item that was already stored */
        let currentItem = result.find( element => {
            return fields.map( field => element[field] === item[field] )
                         .indexOf( false ) === -1;
        } );

        /** If there was no group item, we create one and add it */
        if ( !currentItem ) {

            currentItem = itemKeys.filter( key => fields.indexOf( key ) > -1 )
                                  .reduce( ( obj, key ) => Object.assign( obj, {
                                      [key] : item[key]
                                  } ), {} );

            result.push( currentItem );

        }

        /**
         * Finally we sum all other keys and add them to the already referenced
         * current item
         */
        itemKeys.filter( key => fields.indexOf( key ) === -1 )
                .forEach( key => {
                    if ( !currentItem[key] ) { currentItem[key] = 0; }
                    currentItem[key] = currentItem[key] + item[key];
                } );

        return result;

    }, [] );
}

console.log( sumGroup( input, ["a", "b"] ) );
```

Comment: Reduce is hardly any better than a loop here.

Comment: Thanks but actually very slow. FYI:Timed the function on my laptop at around 88-94 ms. about 90 times slower than regular loops, including the example i gave.

Comment: I did abstract method that can have an array of parameters that you want to index by. Sure `reduce` is almost never better than for loop in terms of performance, but your question was answered with "I tried reduce" ( https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53125960/revisions ), so I decided to write it with reduce ;)